# Unknown plugin dev-expression

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I use the webpack + react in my project. When starting no show errors. But after change file jsx i get this erro: Unknown plugin dev-expression. This is my file configuration:

```
/* webpack.config.js */

var commonLoaders = [
        {test: /.*\.json$/, loader: 'json'},
        {test: /.*\.md$/, loader: 'file'},
        {test: /\.jsx?$/, loaders: ['babel-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/},
        {test: /.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$/, loaders: ['file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&size=16&name=[hash].[ext]', 'image-webpack-loader?optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false']},
        {test: /.*\.(eot|woff|ttf|svg)/, loader: 'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&size=16&name=cd [hash].[ext]'}
    ];

    module.exports = {
        entry: './index.jsx',

        output: {
            filename: './dist/bundle.js'
        },

        resolve: {
            modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
        },

        module: {
            loaders: commonLoaders.concat([{test: /\.styl$/}])
        }
    };

/* package.json */

{
    "author": "Jack Callister",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "font-awesome": "^4.4.0",
        "material-ui": "^0.13.2",
        "react": "^0.14.2",
        "react-dom": "^0.14.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^5.8.22",
        "babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
        "webpack": "^1.11.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm run webpack & npm run serve",
        "webpack": "node_modules/.bin/webpack -w",
        "serve": "python -m SimpleHTTPServer"
    }
}
```

I look other alike question in stackoverflow, but not working for me

What is a problem?

Error:

> ERROR in ./~/material-ui/lib/index.js Module build failed:
>   ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "dev-expression"
>       at PluginManager.subnormaliseString (/Volumes/Ficheiro/Ambiente Desenvolvimento/Workspace
>   nodeJs/react-webpack-boilerplate-master/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/plugin-manager.js:147:13)
>       at PluginManager.add (/Volumes/Ficheiro/Ambiente Desenvolvimento/Workspace
>   nodeJs/react-webpack-boilerplate-master/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/plugin-manager.js:190:40)
>       at File.buildTransformers (/Volumes/Ficheiro/Ambiente Desenvolvimento/Workspace
>   nodeJs/react-webpack-boilerplate-master/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:237:21)
>       at new File (/Volumes/Ficheiro/Ambiente Desenvolvimento/Workspace nodeJs/react-webpack-boilerplate-master/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:139:10)
>       at Pipeline.transform (/Volumes/Ficheiro/Ambiente Desenvolvimento/Workspace
>   nodeJs/react-webpack-boilerplate-master/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:164:16)
>       at transpile (/Volumes/Ficheiro/Ambiente Desenvolvimento/Workspace nodeJs/react-webpack-boilerplate-master/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:12:22)
>       at Object.module.exports (/Volumes/Ficheiro/Ambiente Desenvolvimento/Workspace
>   nodeJs/react-webpack-boilerplate-master/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:69:12)
>   @ ./index.jsx 5:17-39